# Не могу пользоваться полями объекта интерфейса C#

Tags: c#

Изучаю интерфейсы, видел где-то в коде примерно такое

```
ISomething some;
// then
some.Something(); // могу ошибаться, но как-то так там работали с интерфейсом
```

Я сейчас пытаюсь сделать что-то похожее. Насколько помню в интерфейсе можно только описать поля и методы, а реализовывать их нужно уже в классе-наследнике. Может кто-то один, умный специалист и опытный в данной сфере, объяснить мне эти тонкости?

Вот код мой в вижле:

```
// ICar.cs
internal interface ICar
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        string Description { get; }
        public string ReturnName()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
```

```
// Program.cs
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ICar car;
            car.Name = "Tesla Car";
            string x = car.ReturnName();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[interface (C# Reference)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface)

```
class Car : ICar {
  ...
}

ICar car = new Car();
car.Name = "Tesla Car";
...
```

Comment: То есть мы создаём объект интерфейса (ICar car) и затем создаём его объект (= new Car();)?

Comment: @MichaelClifford Мы *объявляем* переменную типа интерфейса и *присваиваем* ей значение ссылки на объект класса, реализующего этот интерфейс.

Comment: спасибо, классное объяснение, а то всегда путался)

Comment: @MichaelClifford Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Хотя ответ уже есть, но всё же дополнительно поясню.
Интерфейс - это, как сейчас модно говорить, *контракт*. Он просто *описывает* способы взаимодействия с объектом класса, который будет реализовывать этот интерфейс. Нельзя создать объект типа интерфейс. Но можно унаследовать от интерфейса класс, создать объект этого класса, и вот этим объектом уже можно пользоваться как интерфейсом, которому этот класс наследует.